# Difference between getAll for a specific index and get for key range

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I'm a bit confused about the differences of approach between using an index and a key range.

In an indexedDB object store with a compound key, such as the array `[ topic, note ]`, in which a part of the compound key, here `topic`, is also an index in the object store, would you please explain whether or not there is a difference between the following? Please note that `k` just returns the key range of all records with the same topic_value.

One reason I ask is because of the statement in the second paragraph of this [MDN document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBIndex/getAll) about using `getAll` on an index concerning a "performance cost" and objects being "created lazily."

Thank you.

```
o = T.objectStore( 'notes' ).index( 'topic' )
req = o.getAll( topic_value );
```

and

```
o = T.objectStore( 'notes' ).
k = IDBKeyRange.bound( [ topic_value, 0 ], [ topic_value + 1, 0 ], false, true ); 
req = o.getAll( k );
```

Answer (score 0):

When you specify a non-IDBKeyRange value to `getAll`, `IDBKeyRange.only(value)` is implied.

For example, `getAll(value)` is equivalent to `getAll(IDBKeyRange.only(value))`.

This applies to both `store.getAll` and `store.index().getAll` as there is no difference between the two.

Comment: Thanks for responding to my question. I believe I understand what you wrote.  However, that''s not what I was attempting to ask; or perhaps I'm missing your point or don't understand what a key is in an index. The variable topic_value isn't a key of a record, but the value of the property 'topic' which is also an index.  Variable k is a range of keys, each an array [ topic, note ]. I'm trying to understand which is better, extracting using an index to get all records of a particular topic or extracting directly from the object store using a key range equivalent to the the same records.

Comment: an index is generally faster at query time but takes up more space. if space is not an issue go with an index.

Comment: I should have wrote also that I'd like to understand what the significance is of the note/warning concerning performance cost of using getAll with an index and being "created lazily".  Does it result in less efficiency than just using the key range on the object store? Thank you.

Comment: You were quicker than me with that response. Thank you.